# AJAX code not working on iPad only

Tags: ajax, ipad

We've created an event check-in page where nonprofits can add volunteers at an event. The page is working great on all platforms besides iPad. (iPhone Safari is working.)

On iPad, clicking `id=add-volunteer` button has no effect. Desired behavior is that clicking the button adds the volunteer name to the list of registered volunteers and saves the user info on the backend. (Other backend tasks such as sending an invite email should occur on the backend as well.)

**HTML**

```
<form id="form-add" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">


<div class="row one-margin-bottom center">
  <div id="new-volunteers" class="small-12 medium-8 small-centered columns">
    <h6 class="left">Add volunteer</h6>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-right small-6 columns">
        <input class="center" id="new-firstname" name="user_firstname" placeholder="First name" type="text" required="">
      </div>

      <div class="input-right small-6 columns">
        <input class="center" id="new-lastname" name="user_lastname" placeholder="Last name" type="text" required="">
      </div>

      <div class="input-right small-12 medium-12 columns">
        <input class="lead center" id="new-email" name="user_email" placeholder="Email address" type="email" required="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="no-margin-top qtr-margin-bottom checkbox center">

      <input type="checkbox" name="invite-optin" id="invite-optin" class="custom-checkbox" checked="">
      <label for="invite-optin">Invite volunteer to openCurrents</label>
    </div>

    <a id="add-volunteer" class="half-margin-bottom button round small secondary">
      Add volunteer
    </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>

<form id="form-checkin" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">

<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 medium-8 small-centered columns">
    <h6 class="left half-margin-bottom">Registered volunteers</h6>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="left small-8 columns">
        <p class="small-text half-margin-top half-margin-bottom"><strong>Name / Email</strong></p>
      </div>

      <div class="right small-4 columns">
        <p class="small-text half-margin-top half-margin-bottom"><strong>Check in</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div id="registered-volunteers" class="small-12 medium-8 small-centered columns">


    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="row">
  <a href="/org-admin/" class="button round small secondary">
    Back to org home
  </a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
let onCheckClick = function(event) {
  let name = event.target.name;
  let elem = $(`#${name}`);
  let userid = elem.val();
  let isChecked = elem.prop("checked");

  $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'openCurrents:event_checkin' event_id %}",
    type: 'POST',
    data : {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[1].value,
      userid: userid,
      checkin: isChecked
    },
    dataType : "json",
    context: document.body
  }).done(function( data ){
    // console.log('checkin request:');
    // console.log(data);
    if (isChecked) {
      let dt = new Date();
      $(`#vol-status-${userid}`).text(`${dt.toLocaleTimeString()}`);
      $(`#vol-status-${userid}`).show();
    }
    else {
      $(`#vol-status-${userid}`).text(`${data.responseText} min.`);
    }
  }).fail(function (data) {
    // console.log('checkin error:')
    // console.log(data);
    elem.prop('checked', false);
    $('#live-dashboard-error').slideDown();
  });;
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  // bind all existing checkbox to checkin
  $("input[name^='vol-checkin']").click(onCheckClick);

  $("#add-volunteer").click(function(event){
    if ($(this).attr('disabled') === 'disabled') {
      $('#live-dashboard-checkin-disabled').slideDown();
      return;
    }

    if ($('#new-firstname').val() == '' || $('#new-lastname').val() == '' || $('#new-email').val() == '') {
      $('#vol-error').slideDown();
    } else if ( !(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test($('#new-email').val() ))  ) {
      $('#vol-error').slideUp();
      $('#email-error').slideDown();
    } else {
      $('#vol-error').slideUp();
      $('#email-error').slideUp();

      let new_firstname = $('#new-firstname').val();
      let new_lastname = $('#new-lastname').val();
      let new_email = $('#new-email').val();
      let invite_optin = $('#invite-optin').prop('checked');
      let process_signup_url;
      let form_data = {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
        user_firstname: new_firstname,
        user_lastname: new_lastname,
        user_email: new_email.toLowerCase()
      };

      if (invite_optin) {
        process_signup_url = "{% url 'openCurrents:process_signup' endpoint=True verify_email=True %}"
        form_data['org_admin_id'] = {{ user.id }};
      }
      else {
        process_signup_url = "{% url 'openCurrents:process_signup' endpoint=True verify_email=False %}"
      }

      form_data['signup_status'] = 'vol'

      $.ajax({
        url: process_signup_url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        dataType : "json",
      }).done(function( data ) {
        // console.log('signup response:')
        // console.log(data);
        let userid = data;

        let form_data = {
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
          userid: userid
        }

        $.ajax({
          url: "{% url 'openCurrents:event_register_live' eventid=event.id %}",
          type: 'POST',
          data: form_data,
          dataType : "json",
        }).done(function( data ) {
          //console.log('register_live response:')
          //console.log(data);
          // hide any error messages present
          $('#vol-exist').slideUp();
          $('#live-dashboard-error-register').slideUp();
          $('#live-dashboard-error').slideUp();
          $('#vol-error').slideUp();
          $('#email-error').slideUp();
          $('#live-dashboard-not-in-progress').slideUp();

          if (data.event_status >= 0) {
            $('#registered-volunteers').prepend(`
              <div class="row"> \
                <div class="left small-9 columns"> \
                  <p class="half-margin-top"> \
                    ${new_firstname} \
                    ${new_lastname} \
                  </p> \
                </div> \

                <div class="right small-3 columns"> \
                    <input {% if checkin_disabled %}disabled{% endif %} type="checkbox" id="vol-checkin-${userid}" name="vol-checkin-${userid}" value="${userid}" class="hidden checkin-checkbox"/> \

                    <label class="checkin-checkbox-icon" for="vol-checkin-${userid}"> \
                      <i class="fa fa-lg fa-check-circle"></i> \
                    </label> \
                </div> \
              </div> \
            `)

            // clear form inputs
            $('#new-firstname').val('');
            $('#new-lastname').val('');
            $('#new-email').val('');
            $('#invite-optin').attr("checked", true);

            // bind new checkbox to checkin
            $(`input[name='vol-checkin-${userid}']`).click(onCheckClick);
            if (data.event_status == 1) {
              $(`input[name='vol-checkin-${userid}']`).trigger('click')
            } else {
              $('#live-dashboard-not-in-progress').slideDown();
            }
          }
          else {
            $('#new-firstname').val('');
            $('#new-lastname').val('');
            $('#new-email').val('');
            $('#invite-optin').attr("checked", true);
            $('#vol-exist').slideDown();
          }
        }).fail( function (data) {
          // console.log('register_live error:')
          // console.log(data);
          $('#live-dashboard-error').slideDown();
        });
      }).fail(function (data) {
        // console.log('signup error:')
        // console.log(data);
        $('#live-dashboard-error').slideDown();
      });

    }
  });
```

Comment: My guess is that the browser doesn't support something your doing? Have you tired hooking the iPad up to the mac and checking the console in Safari?

Comment: I don't actually have an iPad - only replicated the behavior on Browserstack. We originally found the bug with a user's iPad.